# PHP - Capture failed records while reading it from CSV file

Tags: php

I am using PHP code to upload the data from multiple CSV files into database.

Whenever I am inserting the records from CSV file, I want to maintain a separate logs for the records that were unable to insert into database. For e.g In above CSV file,if records 2,3 and 4 were inserted into database but 5 was not inserted because of some reasons, I want to keep a separate log for that. How can I achieve that ?

Here is my sample CSV file data:

[image]

Here is my php code:

```
$csvFile= fopen($dir.'/'.$file,"r");
                    
while (($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE) {
  // Get row data
  $account_code = $line[0];
  $caller_number = $line[1];
  $callee_number = $line[2];
  $context = $line[3];
  $calerid = $line[4]; 
  $source_channel=$line[5];
  $dest_channel=$line[6];
  $lastapp=$line[7];
  $lastdata=$line[8];
  $start_time=$line[9];
  $answer_time=$line[10];
  $end_time=$line[11];
  
  $query = $db->query
("INSERT INTO `cdrnew`(`account_code`, `caller_number`, `callee_number`, `context`, `calerid`, `source_channel`, `dest_channel`, `lastapp`, `lastdata`, `start_time`, `answer_time`, `end_time`)
VALUES ('".$account_code."', '".$caller_number."',  '".$callee_number."', '".$context."', '".$calerid."','".$source_channel."','".$dest_channel."','".$lastapp."','".$lastdata."','".$start_time."','".$answer_time."','".$end_time."')");
}
fclose($csvFile);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "failed records"?

Comment: I don't know, I just said that your question should be more clear, so someone can answer it. When I first read it, I was like what does this mean? Please update your question so others can answer it.

Comment: Okay i will edit it

Answer (score 5):

If the insert fails, the `$query` will return false so,

```
if(!$query) {
  // log
  file_put_contents('<path to log directory>'.date("j.n.Y").'.log', '<error to log>', FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Capturing failed `$query = $db -> query`:

```
if($query) // returns true if successful
{
  // log success
} else {
  // log failed
}
```

Comment: but wouldn't that trigger the execution(query) twice?